# Выходит ошибка в коде при работе с тригером

Tags: java, mysql, исключения, триггер

У меня в БД есть триггер

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `T1` AFTER INSERT ON `reservation` FOR EACH ROW Begin
Update Room
Set roomStatus = "Booked"
where Room.roomNumber = Reservation.roomNumber;
End
```

И когда я выполняю код

```
System.out.print("Введите ваш guestID: ");
int gID = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Выберите какой номер вы хотите забронировать: ");
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from Room;");
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.print("Номер комнаты:"+rs.getInt("roomNumber"));
    System.out.print("  Тип комнаты:"+rs.getString("class"));
    System.out.print("  Статус комнаты:" +rs.getString("roomStatus"));
    System.out.print("  Цена за ночь:"+rs.getFloat("price"));
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
int rNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Введите планируемую дату заезда в таком формате YYYY-MM-DD:");
String sd = keyboard.next();
System.out.println("Введите планируемую дату отъезда в таком формате YYYY-MM-DD:");
String ed = keyboard.next();

stmt.executeUpdate("Insert INTO reservation(roomNumber, guestID, startDate, endDate, checkIn, checkOut) Values('"+rNumber+"', '"+gID+"', '"+sd+"', '"+ed+"', 0, 0);");
```

111 строчка это `stmt.executeUpdate(...`

Выходит ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Reservation.roomNumber' in 'where clause'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
    at com.jdbc.Main.main(Main.java:111)
```

Таблица Reservation:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну дык нету же этой таблицы в источнике данных запроса-то! Да и нельзя в триггере теребить таблицу, на которой этот триггер определён. Ну и `BEGIN-END` в случае единственного запроса в теле триггера - лишний.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `T1` 
AFTER INSERT 
ON `reservation` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE room
    SET roomStatus = "Booked"
    WHERE room.roomNumber = NEW.roomNumber;
```

Comment: а что значит NEW.roomNumber?

Comment: @Stark `NEW` - псевдотаблица с одной записью, содержащая новые значения полей для текущей (изменяемой) записи. Одной записи, той самой, на действия с которой сработал триггер.